# Android import library

Tags: java, android, import, dependencies, r.java-file

I'm trying for hours to import a library into my project.

Library: https://github.com/Eaiman/BitmapHandler

However, when I import it, it happens that Classes like Fragment, FragmentAdapter, and others from `android.support.v4` get an error like they don't exist. This may be a simple question but I'm not used to Java since I am a Python/C++ programmer and I'm not used to this kind of configurations with libraries.

This is my Log:

```
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] Versions found are:
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] Path: /home/name/workspace/BitmapHandler/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject]   Length: 621451
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject]   SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] Path: /home/name/workspace/ViewPagerIndicator-library/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject]   Length: 271754
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject]   SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
[2014-03-07 12:00:17 - MyProject] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

It says (as must as I understand from it) that there are two identical files (.jars) but they have different versions. I don't know how to solve that so I'm asking for your help to not just understand it but to solve this.

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
```

Indicates that the supprot library versions do not match.

Make sure you ave the updated support library.

Copy `android-support-v4.jar` from the below path and paste it to the libs folder of both the library project and your android project.

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the remove the **android-support-v4.jar** file from the **libs** folder from your project.

Good Luck.